# Forced migration between mySQL versions. Receiving #1064 error

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to import a dump created in mySQL 5.0.92 into mySQL 5.1.63. However I am receiving an error.

```
Error
SQL query:

-- -- Database: 'removed_keyboard' -- -- -------------------------------------------------------- -- -- Table structure for table 'bindings' -- CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'bindings' ( 'binding_id' int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, 'game_id' int(5) unsigned NOT NULL, 'layout_id' tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL, 'key_number' tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL, 'normal_action' varchar(128) default NULL, 'normal_group' tinyint(2) unsigned default NULL, 'shift_action' varchar(64) default NULL, 'shift_group' tinyint(2) unsigned default NULL, 'ctrl_action' varchar(64) default NULL, 'ctrl_group' tinyint(2) unsigned default NULL, 'alt_action' varchar(64) default NULL, 'alt_group' tinyint(2) unsigned default NULL, 'altgr_action' varchar(64) default NULL, 'altgr_group' tinyint(2) unsigned default NULL, 'extra_action' varchar(64) default NULL, 'extra_group' tinyint(2) unsigned default NULL, 'image_file' varchar(256) default NULL, PRIMARY KEY ('binding_id')[...]

MySQL said: 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''bindings' (
  'binding_id' int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  'game_id' at line 11
```

What is the error? I'm not familiar with the differences between the different mySQL versions. Is there a noob-friendly list of syntax differences between them?

Thank you! Thank you!

Mike

Comment: Share create table for this particular scene. Some particular difference will be fixed and At least your this problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like (') are used instead of  backticks (`) around the object names -

```
CREATE TABLE 'bindings' (
  'binding_id' int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  'game_id' at line 11...
```

Change these (') with (`) -

```
CREATE TABLE `bindings` (
  `binding_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `game_id` at line 11...
```

- ' is used to quote string literals
- ` is used to quote identifiers (table, column names, and etc.)

Comment: You're right about the quotes. But I get a different error now. Should I start a new question?